# Xubuntu 11.10 slowdown/lag, restarting X doesn't help

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Every once in a while, typically after my computer has been idle for at least 30 minutes or  so, my machine becomes unusably slow. It's hard to describe exactly what's happening -- it's a lag, basically. Mouse movement drags far behind what it should be, clicks take up to 30 seconds to process, applications take a very long time to launch (even from the console).

I've checked htop and the system monitor and CPU/mem usage is normal. No processes appear to be eating cycles or doing anything out of the ordinary. Restarting X has no effect, and even the terminals are significantly slowed.

I've tried killing processes like crazy, including various daemons and xscreensaver, but the only thing that fixes the problem is restarting the machine entirely.

I can't find anything out of ordinary in the logs, dmesg, or anywhere else.

I've turned off power management, to no effect.

I was previously running Ubuntu 10.04 on this machine and never experienced the issue. I also have Debian testing running (also with XFCE), and don't experience the issue.

I have an Nvidia card, and am using the recommended nvidia-current drivers, if that might be relevant.

Does anyone have any idea? I am utterly stumped here, and I'm loving Xubuntu otherwise.

Thanks!